# How many neighbor-swaps does it take to undo a random shuffle of N items?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you have an ordered deck of $N$ items, $e_1, e_2, ... e_N$ and you randomly shuffle them. On average, how many neighbor-swaps does it take to get back to the ordered deck?  For example:

$N=3$.
$D = [1, 2, 3, 4]$.
Random Shuffle: $[1,3,4,2]$
Swaps to get back: 2 (permute 2 and 4, then 2 and 3).

Comment: After reading my question a few times, I realized this is just bubble-sort.  Was able to search and find [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/453692/84216), which appears to answer my question.

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it.

Comment: Why do you think this is bubble-sort? I am quite sure you can find something more efficient!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realizing this is bubble sort, I found the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/453692/84216).

$$\frac{n(n-1)}{4}$$